# Reversing the qr code in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I have made a qr code reader in my application and now i want to retrieve information that's on qr code and that information should land on the form page of my application, like if my qr code has a name,email,address and city in qr code so in the form page i will be having all those fields with empty text boxes and after i snap picture of qr code than that information should land on the specific field on the form page can any one tell me how can i implement it in my application. I have two pages

> page one has a button that has a button "scan" which works as a qr code scanner.
>
> page second has the form page that has text view and empty text boxes for name,email,address and city fields.
>
> so basically when i press button "scan" from first page and after scanning the qr code from it, it should take me to the second page of my app which has form and all the fields should be now filled with all the information that was on qr code.
>   [image]
>   i used http://goqr.me/ (vcard) to make my qr code for testing on form, should i use plain text information to make it much easier or is it ok with what i have used.

please help me out how can i implement this, coding will be much helpful.

Answer (score 2):

in CaptureActivity look for function draw line in which you will find code

```
TextView contentsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contents_text_view);
        CharSequence displayContents = resultHandler.getDisplayContents();
        addcard.bar=displayContents.toString();//this is my edit to get barcode
        addcardnew.bar=displayContents.toString();//use the static string in ur act.
        EncodeActivity.con= displayContents.toString();//this you have to use
        QRCodeEncoder.contents=displayContents.toString();//this is also supply value
```

create a button in CaptureActivity onClick event should be like

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Intent i=new Intent(CaptureActivity.this,EncodeActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("new1", new1);
                i.setAction(Intents.Encode.ACTION);
                i.putExtra(Intents.Encode.FORMAT,temp );
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
    });
```

after this it will take you to encode activity there on onResume code you will find 
a bitmap named bitmap just assign it to bitmap in your activity and call finish();

Comment: i have used zxing library only for scanning qr code and did not know much about it in deep, i implemented only this http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

Comment: check for my edited answer you will find it very useful do let me know in case you still feel any difficulty

Comment: yes i checked your answer but i think it will only load the image information in bitmap format i want the info in the boxes on the page and also edited my question so that you can understand that on which part i am having difficulty.